# Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a project with already deployed indexing to google cloud datastore. We are missing index.yaml, is it possible to recreate index.yaml automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the deployed version of the `index.yaml` if it was uploaded together with your (standard environment) application code, typically with the `default` service/module.

There is a `Diagnose` column in the table on the developer console's [Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) page and a `Tools` drop-down menu for each service version row, with a `Source` option under it:

[image]

Selecting that option directs you to the StackDriver page for the service, where you can see the code for the respective deployed service. Navigate to and select the `index.yaml` file in the left-side column and you'll have the content of the file, which you can copy-paste into your local copy of the file.

Update: accessing the app code is also possible directly from the app's Dashboard page when the respective app service is selected:

[image]