# How to recover source code of Nodejs GAE project

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, data-recovery

I've an application which is deployed. I'd created simple get fetch services on cloud in a project and have deployed it. Unfortunately in confusion b/w the projects, I deleted the project. I can access the web service by fetching through urls but couldn't get the source code. Any help?

Comment: standard or flex environment?

Comment: I search a lot but couldn't find if its standard or flexible. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: In the developer console on the [Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) page yo have a column with the environment

Comment: Thanks. Its standard environment.

Comment: Check if you can see the code in StackDriver - I'm unsure if it works with the 2nd generation standard environment, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499884/4495081

Comment: Thank you so much! It found the source code but is there any way I could restore the source files in the app engine again without manual restore, that might be the last resort.

Comment: The only other thing to try I can think of, which worked for 1st gen standard env, is to use the original python GAE SDK, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code. But chances are low, the node.js tab is not enabled in that doc.

Comment: Although, it didn't worked out. Since I'd 4-5 file, I manually created them and imported the code. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem.Side note: you may want to use this opportunity to get on the version control system use habit - recovery would have been trivial ;)

Comment: Yeh. I just connected bitbucket and pushed my code a minute ago. :) Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment it's only possible to download Java, Python, PHP and Go application's source code.

What I can recommend you is to submit a Feature Request through this [link](http://issuetracker.google.com/) asking for this feature also for Node.js. Also you may consider using [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/), which is free and can help you mitigate this kind of issues in the future.