# Undoing a routes deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, google-cloud-platform, gae-module

I had some existing GAE services configured with their dispatch routes. I wanted to add a dispatch route to a new service.
So, I executed the following command

`gcloud app deploy dispatch.yml`

on this file

```
dispatch:
  - url: "<my path>/eth/*"
    service: my-new-service
```

However, all the existing routes for existing services got reset. How can I undo it or restore the previous routes?

Answer (score 0):

The `dispatch.yaml` file is an application level configuration, shared by all app's services. All routes for all services need to be aggregated into the file.

Deploying one version of the file overwrites the previous one, so you need not delete from it the routes you want to preserve.

AFAIK there is no way to revert a `dispatch.yaml` deployment from the cloud console, you just need to re-deploy a previous version of the file. Hopefully you had it under version control.

If you didn't version control the file but you happen to store it somewhere inside the directory of one of your services (i.e. considered part of the service's app code) and you still have a version of that service deployed you may be able to find it by checking the source code of that deployed version:

- if it's a standard environment service you could try [the official recipe](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code) (but which uses the GAE SDK, not the cloud SDK). Or try accessing it live, see my answer to [Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884)
- if it's a flexible environment service see [Downloading App Engine source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181876/downloading-app-engine-source-code)

**Note**: be aware that there are other shared configs (see [Optional configuration files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuration-files#optional_configuration_files)) which need similar attention.