# How to download source code from google app engine standard (appcfg.py is deprecated)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

How to download source code from google app engine standard when the appcfg.py is deprecated by the google.

Answer (score 3):

The `gcloud` SDK doesn't (yet) have an equivalent capability. From [Migrating to Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration):

> As a result of the deprecation of the `appcfg` tool and the standalone
>   App Engine SDK, the following features are currently not supported in
>   Cloud SDK:
>
> - [Downloads of your application's source code with AppCfg.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code)

However, despite being deprecated, the GAE SDK remains so far functional, so you can still use its `appcfg.py` download capability, at least until its announced shutdown date - July 30, 2020 (see also [Feature Deprecations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/)). Hopefully by that time there will be an equivalent `gcloud` functionality.

Separately from straight downloading the app code it may be possible (but more tedious) to view the files and restore them them by copy-pasting their content, see [Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884).